# Using Variable in other scripts/ pulling variables from script

Tags: powershell

I have multiple Variables in my first Script

```
$var1= Moon
$var2= Sun
$var3= Earth
```

Some lines with var1, var2, var3...

...

...

---

In a few other scripts I have lines which need those variables but I do not want to define them in those scripts, only in the first one.

**EDIT: Basically I am trying to pull variables from anther script, while only running the pulling script.**

```
Write-Host"$var1"
Write-Output"$var2"
```

...

...

I've found a few answers online, but those did not really help me... hope someone here can :D

Comment: You can [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the first script with the variables in the second script.

Comment: You can also persist variable contents by [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7.1).

Answer (score 0):

@Emil Horstmann

Well to start you can "dotsource(. C:\test\test.ps1)" the first script from the second one meaning that all the variables will be loaded with it.

You can also pass arguments between files:

```sh
# file1.ps1

$var1= Moon
$var2= Sun
$var3= Earth

C:test\test.ps1 $var1 $var2 $var3

############################################################

# file2.ps1

write-output $args[0] # moon
write-output $args[1] # sun
write-output $args[2] # earth
```

Another option is to write them to a file and pull them out in the new script (xml, json, csv, etc.)
Or you make a file3.ps1 wich calls both the scripts while passing variables to them.

EDIT:
After some testing i found that if you call the second file from the first the variable can just be used. Your sample code will work.

```sh
# File1.ps1
$var1= "Moon"
$var2= "Sun"
$var3= "Earth"

C:\test\test.ps1

# test.ps1
write-host $var1
write-output $var2
write-warning $var3
```

Your original code would have worked outside of the syntax errors.

Comment: I am trying not to start the second script from the first script. I also want to start the second scrip without even touching the first one, but still be able to use the variables.

Comment: Powershell uses sessions wich are basicly the terminal windows. If you want to use these variables in other scripts without having to define them you need to add them to your $profile (notepad $profile) wich will run everytime you start powershell include .ps1 files. Just keep in mind that the powershell ise uses a different profile than the normal terminal.